# Ruby on Rails - using :include in Model of different schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, schema, models

I am working with Ruby on Rails models. I have two models belonging to two different schemas. Two models have parent child relationship. e.g

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "schema2"
end
```

Model Group is in schema1 and customer is in schema2. If I do this to load Groups using following code:

```
self.paginate(:all, :page => currentpage, :per_page => per_page, :include => :customer)
```

I get the error
"schema1.Customer" is an undefined name" as it is trying to find Customer in schema1 instead of schema2.

How can I change this query (or this :include) to indicate that customer is in schema2. I tried to add class_name in has_one relationship in Group as
`has_one :customer, class_name=>"Customer"`, but it doesn't solve the problem, and I get the same error.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can load them only separate:

```
@groups = self.paginate(:all, :page => currentpage, :per_page => per_page)
@customers = Customer.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @groups.map(&:id)})
```